# str_replace or string extraction remove carriage return

Tags: php, replace, extract

The code below return the content of a script tag of a HTML page, $fullink. My problem is that everything is on only one line, carriage returns deseappeared. How can I fix it ?

```
$page = file_get_html($fullink);

        function extractString($string, $start, $end) {
            $string = " ".$string;
            $ini = strpos($string, $start);
            if ($ini == 0) return "";
            $ini += strlen($start);
            $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
            return substr($string, $ini, $len);
        }
        $string = file_get_html($fullink);
        $brut = extractString($string, 'resultslines', '//--');
        $brut2 = str_replace(',',',<br/>',$brut);
        echo '<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" SRC="raceresults.js"></SCRIPT>';
        echo '<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript"><!-- \n resultslines' . $brut2 .'//--><br/></SCRIPT>';
```

Current output :

```
<!--resultslines=["dir=2013_EMF_Bogny_Sur_Meuse", "longname=2013 EMF FrenchCup Rd1 : Bogny Sur Meuse", "firstlap=20", "normallap=32", "holeshotindex=1", "time=61440", "laps=1", "starttime=1752", "date=1409502349", "players:", "slot=0", "uid=6864", "number=191", "bike=rm125", "name=Eddie Ozel", "times:", "0 0 2543", "0 1 3411", "0 2 3790", "0 3 4483", "0 4 5231", "0 5 5838", "0 6 6144", "0 7 6779", "0 8 7212", "0 9 7582", "0 10 8282", "0 11 8857", "0 12 9531", "0 13 10047", "0 14 12720", "0 15 12916", "0 16 13252", "0 17 13949", "0 18 14384", "0 19 15023", "0 20 15565", "0 21 16051", "0 22 16560", "0 23 17079", "0 24 17369", "0 25 17734", "0 26 18180", "0 27 18452", "0 28 18589", "0 29 18932", "0 30 19166", "0 31 20259", "0 32 20585", "0 33 20941", "0 34 21275", "0 35 22589", "0 36 23247", "0 37 23799", "0 38 24048", "0 39 25224", "0 40 25610", "0 41 26007", "0 42 26726", "0 43 27233", "0 44 27774", "0 45 28220", "0 46 28816", "0 47 29064", "0 48 29393", "0 49 30133", "0 50 30465", "0 51 31171", "0 52 31738", "0 53 32224", "0 54 32698", "0 55 33150", "0 56 33438", "0 57 33781", "0 58 34216", "0 59 34515", "0 60 34670", "0 61 34990", "0 62 35231", "0 63 35497", "0 64 35780", "0 65 36117", "0 66 36467", "0 67 37106", "0 68 38137", "0 69 38690", "0 70 38948", "0 71 39566", "0 72 39916", "0 73 40497", "0 74 41169", "0 75 41731", "0 76 42248", "0 77 42724", "0 78 43333", "0 79 43566", "0 80 43907", "0 81 44714", "0 82 45824", "0 83 46484", "0 84 47028", "0 85 47514", "0 86 47991", "0 87 48442", "0 88 48726", "0 89 49066", "0 90 49493", "0 91 49786", "0 92 49935", "0 93 50219", "0 94 50454", "0 95 50781", "0 96 51105", "0 97 51441", "0 98 51785", "0 99 52567", "0 100 53108", "0 101 53653", "0 102 53898", "0 103 58629", "0 104 58967", "0 105 59371", "0 106 60034", "0 107 60549", "0 108 61101", "0 109 61610", "0 110 62274", "0 111 62454", "0 112 62782", "0 113 63642", "0 114 64049", "0 115 64680", "0 116 68983", "0 117 69522", "0 118 70025", "0 119 70490", "0 120 70780", "0 121 71087", "0 122 71512", "0 123 71794", "0 124 71927", "0 125 73390", "0 126 73667", "0 127 74064", "0 128 74374", "0 129 74715", "0 130 75056", "0 131 75728", "0 132 76972", "0 133 77537", "0 134 77748", "0 135 78481", "0 136 79002", "0 137 79316", "0 138 80092", "0 139 80622", "0 140 81238", "0 141 82723", "0 142 83446", "0 143 83624", "0 144 83924", "0 145 84752", "0 146 85050", "0 147 85712", "", ] print_race_analysis(resultslines)  //--><br/>
```

Output needed :

```
<!--
resultslines=["dir=2013_EMF_Bogny_Sur_Meuse",
"longname=2013 EMF FrenchCup Rd1 : Bogny Sur Meuse",
"firstlap=20",
"normallap=32",
"holeshotindex=1",
"time=61440",
(...)
"0 146 85050",
"0 147 85712",
"",
]
print_race_analysis(resultslines)

//-->
```

Comment: Bad code. Ok, you need, perhaps, `str_replace(',',",\n",$brut);` not `,<br/>`. Please read PHP Guide and check PHP tutorial and good PHP samples.

Comment: @Peter Krauss I answered myself, in the code you can see <br/> as I tried \r\n and other returns too, the mistake was about quotes instead of double ones.

Comment: Another things like repeat `file_get_html($fullink)` as $page and $string... You try to use a `preg_replace` instead your `extractString()`?

Comment: no, I didn't. I only tried what I found using Google, I'm not really PHP friendly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that was tricky. In fact, as you can see I used echo '' to display my code and \r or \n just print with quotes.
To insert carriage returns, I had to use double quotes --> echo "" and it works.